# Characterizing the behavior of the solutions of $y’’-q(x)y=0, y(0)=a \ne 0, y'(0)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Consider IVP $$y’’-q(x)y=0, y(0)=a, y’(0)=1$$ where $q(x)$ is continuous and positive on $\mathbb R$. Then my observation is as

If $a>0$, every solution is convex and hence strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$,   because solutions start with positive value and remains convex as long as $y>0$. Again, if $a<0$, then every solution is concave and hence strictly  decreasing on $(-\infty, 0]$, because solutions start with negative  value and remains concave as long as $y<0$.

Please comment or correct my concept . Thank you.

Comment: Second order DE needs two initial conditions. What's $y'(0)$?

Comment: This is a second order differential equation, so you need two initial conditions to specify the behavior of a solution. For example, there are solutions with $y(0)>0$ and $y'(0)<0$. Some of those go to $+\infty$ while others cross into the negative and go to $-\infty$.

Comment: @SolubleFish if f(0)>0, then $y”=q(x)y>0$ , then how can it goes to decreasing. Please give one counter example .

Comment: I have edited your title to better reflect your question. Let me know if I made a mistake.

Comment: @Sidharth Ghoshal thank you.

Comment: With $q(x) = 1$, $y(x) = 2a e^{-x} - ae^{x}$ is a solution with $y(0) = a$, but, if $a>0$, we have $y(x)\to -\infty$ as $x\to+\infty$. Basically, if it starts decreasing, it will slow down, but it may not slow down fast enough and may reach $y=0$.